# is there any difference between this two parts of code?

Tags: if-statement, nested, logical-operators

Is there any difference (logical? performance?) in the following:

```
if(a==1)
{
    if(b==2)
    //some code
}


if(a==1 && b==2)
{
//same code
}
```

Comment: There's no difference logically, and there probably isn't any difference in the underlying machine code, in most (if not all) cases.

Comment: Assuming your language uses short-circuit evaluation for `&&` (probably), there is no difference.

Comment: The first one actually enters the first if statement if `a == 1`. However, the second one just skips the if statement if one or both are false. That said, they are essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Nathan: Are you referring to some subtle intricacy involving side-effects?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a==1)
{
    // Except you can place some code in here if you get in the first if-statement 

    if(b==2)
    {
        //you need to use curly brackets in the 2nd if statement to, except if you execute one line
          of code.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a very high level, the compiler will turn that code into assembly and the assembler will turn that into machine code.  I'm not sure how different Instruction Set Architectures might vary, but for the ones I'm familiar with, such as ARM and MIPS, there is no way to write a compound if statement in one line of assembly.  The compiler will basically turn

`if(a == 1 && b == 1)
    //some code`

into

`if(a == 1){
    if(b == 1)
        //some code
}`

so it does not matter from both a logical or performance standpoint, especially because many compilers do so much optimization anyway.  But like Andreas said, you can add additional code outside the second if statement in the nested example, which may or may not affect the evaluation of the nested condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is no logical difference.  "if A and B then... " is the same logically as "if A then if B then..."

There are lots of these kinds of equivalencies:
p & ( q | r ) is equivalent to ( p & q ) | ( p & r )

If you want to investigate further, start with *DeMorgan's Laws*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws